# why strchr returns not a NULL when the second argument is a string into a single quotation marks ('text')

Tags: c, quotation-marks, strchr

I tried to write implementation of the `strchr()`.

```
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
(unsigned char)c;
    while (*s)
    {
        if (*s == c)
            return ((char *)s);
        s++;
    }
    if (c == '\0')
        return ((char *)s);
    return (NULL);
}
```

It works similar in most of cases except this one:

```
printf("%s\n", strchr("Whats up with you, men", '  up'));
```

`strchr` returns

```
 p with you, men
```

while me version `ft_strchr` returns `NULL`

I'm curious why `strchr` behaves which way. `' up'` converted to `unsigned char` is 'p' (as `int` 538998128).

Also I found here different implementation and it behave as strchr even with this data.

```
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c) {
    while (*s != (unsigned char) c) {
        if (!*s)
            return NULL;
        s++;}
    return (char *)s;
}
```

Also my version is different I guess they should work similar but they don't. I really interested why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(unsigned char)c;` on a line by itself doesn't change the type of `c`, it is still an `int`.

Comment: You are passing in several characters `'  up'`  , but treating it as a single character when you do the comparison- this is going to give you issues if you actually intend to search for more than 1 character. You also have to figure out how your compiler treats a character literal containing more than one character `'  up`  as that is implementation defined - perhaps your compiler only keeps the last `p` or the first space in your multi character literal.

Comment: @nos thanks, I understand that, it was just a test case. The problem was incorrect casting (it should be in expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression:

```
*s == c
```

The term `*s`, which is of type `char`, has a range of either -128 to 127 or 0 to 255, depending on whether or not `char` is signed or unsigned.  The value 538998128 of `c` is outside of this range, so the comparison will never be true.

At the start of the function, you have this line:

```
(unsigned char)c;
```

But this does nothing.  It casts the value of `c` to an `unsigned char` and does nothing with the resulting value.  It does not change the value of `c`.

The other implementation you show casts `c` to `unsigned char` and *then* compares that casted value with `*s`.  That's why the other implementation gives the expected result.